# Nginx On Digital Ocean Restart Fails and Show Not Running, But Site is Being Served

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean

I have a droplet that I initially set up host gitlab, just the stock installation. My trying to modify it to support other, very light weight sites. I followed the instructions from the Digital Ocean tutorial.

I followed all the steps and when attempting to restart

`root@git ~# service nginx restart
 * Restarting nginx nginx                                                                            [fail]`

I've done some extensive searches of the web and got turned on to `nginx -t`.

`nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`

When I check the nginx status:

`service nginx status
nginx is not running`

or

`/etc/init.d/nginx status
 * nginx is not running`

I restarted my droplet and the netstat comes back with nginx listening. But when I run service --status-all the nginx line is :

`[ - ]  nginx`

What am I missing?

EDIT:
Adding the output of `ps -ef | grep ngin` as requested:

```
root       862   858  0 Jul19 ?        00:00:00 runsv nginx
root       875   862  0 Jul19 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/nginx
root       878   862  0 Jul19 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /opt/gitlab/embedded/sbin/nginx -p /var/opt/gitlab/nginx
gitlab-+   894   878  0 Jul19 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process                                   
root      4387  3134  0 20:35 pts/0    00:00:00 grep ngin
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `ps -ef | grep nginx` to your question?

Comment: @htanata Added the requested output.

Comment: You may have two nginx binaries installed on your system. The one currently running is at `/opt/gitlab/embedded/sbin/nginx`. I'm not sure if that's what the tutorial recommends instead of one that comes from Ubuntu APT package. Try stopping that using `sudo /opt/gitlab/embedded/sbin/nginx -s stop` and starting another one using `sudo service nginx start` or `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start`. You may also want to check the error log at `/var/log/nginx/error.log` and add that to the question. It's also helpful if you can link to the tutorial that you followed.

Comment: @htanata Did it got this:
```root@git ~# /opt/gitlab/embedded/sbin/nginx -s stop
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/opt/gitlab/embedded/logs/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2015/07/23 19:29:17 [notice] 6706#0: signal process started
2015/07/23 19:29:17 [error] 6706#0: open() "/opt/gitlab/embedded/logs/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Does the file `/opt/gitlab/embedded/logs/error.log` exist? What's the output of `ps -ef | grep nginx` now? If nginx is no longer running, you can try `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start` and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Try sudo killall -KILL nginx to kill any old processes and restart again.

Comment: try to reboot your droplet using "reboot" command.